# Set a text area to required field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have a textarea which i want to set it to required. I'm trying to use the rulefor from the fluentvalidation but still not happening something.

i have try also too to use the [required] etc. Someone can give me a hand with this?

**Here is my code:**

Model:

```
public class MainValidator : AbstractValidator<Main>
{
    public MainValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Message).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required field");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Serverside:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Message).NotNull().WithMessage("Required field");
```

I could not find that easyli as I thought sources of `RuleFor` method, so you can just try this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Message).NotEmpty().NotNull().WithMessage("Required field");
```

Also, the clientside:

```html
<textarea required id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FluentValidation.AspNetCore 8.1.3

I had same problem and I resolved this way:

Validator

```
public ContactValidator(){ 
    RuleFor(x => x.Message).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Message Required").Length(10, 400).WithMessage("Message must be between 10 and 400 characters");
}
```

Model

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]//<-- Add this line to work
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<textarea asp-for="Message" name="Message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```